# NG ignorig arguments when running in series

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-scripts

I have a dummy multi-project Angular workspace created using Angluar CLI as described here https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries, just in my workspace I have both the library and the application, meaning that I executed the following commands:

```sh
ng new my-workspace --create-application=false
cd my-workspace
ng generate library my-lib
ng generate application my-app
```

I wanted to create a npm script in package json that will create production builds of both the library and the application, so in `package.json` I added:

```
"scripts":{
  // other scripts here
  "build-all-prod": "ng build my-lib --prod && ng build my-app --prod"
}
```

however I'm not getting the prod build of the library when executing `npm run build-all-prod`.

If I have just `ng build my-lib --prod` in the above script then I get the prod build of the library. I also get the prod build of library when the order of `ng build` commands is switched (aka. first ng build the app then the lib). It looks like the `--prod` argument is ignored before `&&` for some reason.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

OK, the issue was not that the `--prod` was ignored, but the fact that building the app also rebuilds a library to be Ivy compatible (makes it non-prod, because Ivy libraries are not supposed to be published)

For more info see this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/38859